# Mirror iframe page with another iframe (making twin iframes)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, iframe

i am working on some project, there i need a webpage.which have only this kind of facility. By using html i know that we can use multiple tabs in a single tab by using iframe, but each iframe works differently. What i need is, suppose i have two iframes in a single tab of chrome, so if i open a website in 1st iframe it should also open in another i frame.
So making it more clear here is a simple example: suppose i have 5 iframes with YouTube in those frames, so i click on comment in one frame but it should be clicked in each iframe.
And when i type 'hi' in one iframes YouTube comment box, it should be typed in each of the 5 iframes YouTube comment box. And when i click on post, it should be posted simultaneously at the same time in each of the 5 iframes.
So i want to make twin pages using iframes.
Hope you guys understanding my question..

Comment: We are not here to do your homework. Post your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some general guidance:

You cannot access an element from JS on your client directly need to either :
use .contentWindow.document for Vanilla Js or Contents() for Jquery

Jquery W3school e.g.
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_contents.asp

here I have 2 iframes: the code is repeated but it severs to show the example

what you need to do is clean it so its not repeated then transfer the values or make a more robust transfer - e.g. loop though elements , pass parameters

```
 <iframe id="myFrame" src="/your-iframe" style="your style"></iframe>


    <iframe id="myFrame2" src="/your-iframe" style="your style"></iframe>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {

/iframe 1
      var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
           var elmnt1 = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsById("yourelement");
      elmnt1.style.display = "none";

/iframe 2
        var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame2");
      var elmnt1 = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsById("yourelement");
      elmnt1.style.display = "none";

    }
    </script>
```

this is just do illustrate the idea :
now you build the client side around this idea